# Android Room - Increment two fields with one @Query

Tags: android, sql, android-room

I would like to increment two fields with one @Query but it's not working:

```
@Query("UPDATE assets SET amount = amount + :amount AND  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + :value WHERE id =:id")
void updateAmount(String id, float amount, float value);
```

amount is being set to zero.

Comment: I don;t know about android-room, but in SQL you use comma (,) between the two values being set, not `AND`: `SET amount = amount + :amount ,  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + :value `

Answer (score 0):

As tinazmu has said the need to separate the columns to be SET with a comma. Without the comma then you are SETing just the one column according to the **one expression** so you are saying SET amount to be the value of

- the amount column + the passed amount ANDed with the value of the accumulated_sum + the passed value (i.e. amount will be 0 or 1 due to the AND returning true (1) or false (0)).

So what you want is :-

```
@Query("UPDATE assets SET amount = amount + :amount,  /*<<<<< comma instead of AND */ accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + :value WHERE id =:id")
```

The following demonstrates the above :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS assets;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS assets (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, amount REAL, accumulated_sum REAL);
INSERT INTO assets (amount, accumulated_sum) VALUES(100,1000),(0,0),(100,0),(0,100);
SELECT amount + 10, accumulated_sum + 10, amount + 10 AND  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + 0 FROM assets;
SELECT amount + 10, accumulated_sum + 10, amount + 10 AND  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + 25 FROM assets;
SELECT amount + 0, accumulated_sum + 10, amount + 10 AND  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + 0 FROM assets;
SELECT amount + 0, accumulated_sum + 10, amount + 10 AND  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + 25 FROM assets;
UPDATE assets SET amount = amount + 10 AND  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + 25;
SELECT * FROM assets;
DELETE FROM assets;
INSERT INTO assets (amount, accumulated_sum) VALUES(100,1000),(0,0),(100,0),(0,100);
UPDATE assets SET amount = amount + 10, /*<<<<<< comma instead *AND*/  accumulated_sum = accumulated_sum + 25;
SELECT * FROM assets;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS assets;
```

So when run then

1. The assets table if it exists is DROPed.
2. The assets table is created.
3. 4 rows are added with various values for the amount and accumulated_sum columns
4. 4 Queries are run to show how 0 and non-zero value affect the result (the third column), as opposed to your expected result (first and second columns).

   1. amount passed is **10** and the value passed is **0** [image]
   2. amount passed is **10** and the value passed is **25** [image]
   3. amount passed is **0** and the value passed is **0** [image]
   4. amount passed is **0** and the value passed is **25** [image]
   5. The rows are UPDATEd according to your Query (the amount passed is **10** and the value passed is **25**) except all rows are updated as there is no WHERE clause.
   6. The rows are queried after the update [image]
   7. All rows are deleted
   8. The original rows are inserted again.
   9. The suggested UPDATE is run (the amount passed is **10** and the value passed is **25**) except all rows are updated as there is no WHERE clause.
   10. The The rows are queried after the update [image]

**i.e. The suggested change updates both columns as expected.**